# How to use NSComboBox in iPhone

Tags: iphone

M a new comer to iPhone world ,i want to use NSComboBox(DropDown list somewhere) in my application. but not having any idea....m totally blank about NSCombobox...could any one guide me..Thank you.....

Answer (score 3):

The iOS Cocoa Touch framework doesn't include anything like an NSComboBox.  You might want to look into using the combination of a UITextField plus a "pop-up" UIPickerView for list selection.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response..But I have allready seen somewhere in Application,I jst wanna to say,iPhone supports NSCombobox....but question arises HOW?

Answer (score 2):

`NSComboBox` does not exist on the iPhone.  It's part of the AppKit framework, which means it only exists on the Mac.  The iPhone's GUI framework is called UIKit.

Comment: ...and `UIPickerView` is the semantic equivalent: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html

Comment: Thank you for your quick response..But I have allready seen somewhere in Application,I jst wanna to say,iPhone supports NSCombobox....but question arises HOW?

Answer (score 0):

You could always write your own.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you open wrong project style. Because NSComboBox is under Mac Application.
You should use project for iPhone application.